# calling $.ajax without having my canvas page being redirected to post url

Tags: facebook, jquery

I want to submit a form from my Facebook canvas app via ajax.
If I run my app outside of facebook, it works fine. However, if I do the ajax call running as a Facebook canvas app, the user is redirected to the the ajax post url!
The server response is valid json.

I've spent over an hour on this.
I found that Facebook has a [deprecated FBJS ajax api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/#ajax). The new js api does not provide any ajax functionallity. The documentation on the deprecated API listed above states:

> If you are building a new app on Facebook.com, please implement your
>   app using HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

What is the magic recipe to make an ajax post from a canvas app?

The relevant code boils down to this:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action, // I tried also submitting to the apps.facebook.com/... url, but it made no difference
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                    alert('TESTING - WORKS!!');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A night's sleep does wonders to your mind. It was very late yesterday when I posted this question.
When I woke up this morning I knew what to check for. The action I was posting to via ajax was in a controller that required Facebook authentication... Moved the action to a different controller and it now works. solved